# 100% networking-related question put on hold as off-topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

This is a reopen request for [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54922/how-to-setup-network-interfaces-for-tcpreplay), which was put on hold as off-topic for being configuration-related. I've provided quotes from the help center that contradict this decision, however the moderator responded with an unrelated remark instead of addressing the contradiction.

---

Moderator:

> Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are
>   off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on Server Fault for
>   a business network. Routing happens on packets between networks,
>   bridging happens on frames on the same network.

Me:

> From the help center's off-topic list: "configuration or operation of
>   computers/servers **not directly related to networking;**". My
>   understanding was that Network Engineering was split from Server Fault
>   specifically to separate network-related questions from all other
>   configuration-related questions. How can a question about network
>   routing can be off-topic on Network Engineering?
>
> From the on-topic list: "servers operating as a router/switch/firewall;".

Moderator:

> Right, but there is also the caveat that the manufacturer must offer
>   optional, paid support, and you do not have that for Linux. Also, most
>   businesses, will not actually try to use a server for a router or
>   switch because of the performance hit.

Answer (score -1):

The response is not unrelated. On the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page from which you quoted:

> **and meets the following requirements**
>
> - under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to
>     answer your question);
> - hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class
>     devices);

Comment: Frankly, this doesn't make any sense to me. Why would you have a Network Engineering stack exchange which is limited like this? This is not at all obvious or helpful to people looking to solve network-related problems. In any case this is not the main issue for me, so can you move this question to Server Fault then (or wherever it is on-topic)?

Comment: You can simply Edit, Copy All, and Paste into a question on your chosen site. If it is for a business network (another requirement for NE), then [sf] would be the place to ask, otherwise it would be [su] or something like [unix.se].